# Rounding values in C++. Why do printf, iostream and round function [could] behave differently, depending on the Visual Studio and Windows version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, printf, rounding

What started as a very simple problem, is now getting a nightmare.  Rounding values in C++ behaves differently depending on quite some factors.

Start with the following simple piece of code, where you pass values just in the middle of 2 integer values to other functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void print(double d);
extern void stream(double d);
extern void rounding(double d);

int main()
{
   for (auto i=0;i<10;++i)
      print(i+0.5);
   printf("\n");

   for (auto i=0;i<10;++i)
      stream(i+0.5);
   printf("\n");

   for (auto i=0;i<10;++i)
      rounding(i+0.5);
   printf("\n");
}
```

The 3 functions print out the values in 3 different ways: using `printf`, using `operator<<` and using the `round` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void print(double d)
{
   printf("%.0lf ",d);
}

void stream(double d)
{
   std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << d << " ";
}

void rounding(double d)
{
   auto r = round(d);
   printf("%.0lf ",r);
}
```

In all these cases I want to print out the value without digits after the decimal point.

I get all these combinations:

Compile with Visual Studio 2015 or 2017, run on Windows Server 2019, build 14393:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Compile with Visual Studio 2015 or 2017, run on Windows 10, build 19041:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

As you can see, using `iostream`s, `operator<<` suddenly decides to use Bankers Rounding starting from this Windows version.

Compile with Visual Studio 2019, run on Windows Server 2019, build 14393:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Compile with Visual Studio 2019, run on Windows 10, build 19041:

```
0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10
0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now the `printf` function also starts to use Bankers Rounding (which wasn't the case when compiled with VS2015 or VS2017).

The page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-fprintf-l-fwprintf-fwprintf-l?view=msvc-160 states that you can get the old behavior back if you link in the  `legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj` object file.  And indeed, if you link this in, then you get this:

Compile with Visual Studio 2019, link with legacy object file, run on Windows 10, build 19041:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the old behavior back for the streaming output operator.

Is anyone else struggling with this problem as well?
What is the best solution to get a consistent rounding?
Since the C standard clearly specifies how the `round` function should behave (round upwards to +/- infinity depending on the sign of the value), it seems logical to have `printf` and `operator<<` to behave like this as well.  So should we tell our developers to prevent using the output operator (more specifically, `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision`) when streaming floating point values?

To make things even worse: some external modules are written in JavaScript, which has even a different way of rounding (always rounds towards +infinity, even for negative numbers).
As I said in the beginning: what started as a simple problem, is now becoming a consistency nightmare.

Did you encounter the same problem?  And how did you handle it?

Comment: Have a read of [Floating-point migration issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/floating-point-migration-issues?view=msvc-160)

Comment: To throw a spanner into the works, I'm running Windows 10, build 1904***2*** compiling with Visual Studio 2019, and I get `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` output for all 3 cases.

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/floating-point-support?view=msvc-160 _"... In most cases, the result produced is within +/-1 ulp of the correctly rounded result,..."_

Comment: Does the behavior also depend on the C++ standard selected in Visual Studio? The default standard is C++14.

Comment: Compiled with following options in a 64-bit VS Shell: /c /EHsc /Zi /Ox /fp:precise /MD.  It's native code, no UWP, no Store app, no .Net, just plain C++.  @Nick, which options did you use?

Comment: @Nick, I am using compiler version 19.22.27906.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @Patrick Well, I don't know what I'm doing, so default options for a debug build in a vcxproj: `/c /ZI /JMC /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt` - Take whatever you need from that cause honestly I only know what like 3 of those switches do. Compiler is 19.28.29914.

Comment: @Nick, I compiled again using my version of CL (19.22.27906), and used your options (but I removed the /D and the /Fo and /Fd options).  When running the result on a non-development machine with Windows 10, version 20H2, it doesn't run because the debug DLL's were missing.  I then replaced /MDd by /MD and rebuilt.  The resulting exe runs on my non-development machine but still shows 0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10 on the first and second line.  When I link in legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj the output using printf shows 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.  So it must be compiler-version related or debug-DLL related.

Comment: @Nick, which Windows 10 version are you using?

Comment: @Patrick 10.0.19042 Build 19042

Comment: @Nick, when I copy the debug DLL's (msvcp140d.dll, msvcp140_1d.dll, vcruntime140d.dll, vcruntime140_1d.dll, ucrtbased.dll) to my non-development machine, I get exactly the same results as you (all showing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, even for the stream implementation.  So the difference seems to be there.  If you compile with debug, the stream operator rounds up.  If you compile without debug, it uses bankers rounding.  Strange.

Comment: @Nick, I recompiled and tested this again on my personal PC which has compiler version 19.23.28106.4.  When compiled with the debug libraries (/MDd) I get 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 in all cases.  When compiled without debug libraries (/MD) I get 0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10 for the first 2 cases.  Aaaaaaaaaaaargh....

Answer (score 1):

[round, roundf, roundl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/round-roundf-roundl?view=msvc-160):Rounds a floating-point value to the nearest integer value.

[printf, _printf_l, wprintf,_wprintf_l](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-160):Starting in Windows 10 version 2004 (build 19041), the printf family of functions prints exactly representable floating point numbers according to the IEEE 754 rules for rounding.In previous versions of Windows, exactly representable floating point numbers ending in '5' would always round up. IEEE 754 states that they must round to the closest even digit (also known as "Banker's Rounding").This change only affects programs built using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 and later. To use the legacy floating point rounding behavior, link with [legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/link-options?view=msvc-160).

std::fixed << std::setprecision(0):The so-called rounding six to five leaving a double means that if it happens to be 0.5, it will be approximated to make the previous digit an even number.

Comment: That's indeed what I observed.  My point is: how to correctly handle this behavior in an application, and explaining to a customer that the output of your application depends on the Windows version.  If the user types 2.5 in a entry field, and then generates a report where no digits after the decimal point are wanted, then he will see 3 in pre-19041 versions of Windows, and 2 in Windows versions starting from 19041.
We can revert to the old behavior by linking in the legacy object file, but only for printf functions.  iostream logic keeps on using Bankers logic.  Explain that to a customer.

Comment: Compiler options also seem to influence the behavior.  When compiled with /MD and running on Windows 10 20H2, I get 0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10 for the first 2 cases (printf and streaming operator) When compiled with /MDd and running on Windows 10 20H2, I get 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 for the first 2 cases.  When running either exe on Windows Server 2019, I always get 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.  Is this expected behavior or simply a bug???

Comment: When compiled with /MD and /MDd running on Windows 10 20H2, I get 0 2 2 4 4 6 6 8 8 10 for the first 2 cases. I am using visual studio2019 16.10.0.

Comment: We could reproduce the problem on several machines, and it was checked by multiple of our colleagues.  The problem has been logged at Microsoft now.